# Resilience with SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We are trying to work on a Live - DR model for SQS queue.

We have two different account in AWS:

1. eu-west (Account no 1234)
2. us-east (Account no 4567)

Our application resides in both account (ACTIVE - PASSIVE).

- In a normal scenario, EU-WEST is active and US-EAST inactive.
- When we failover for DR, US-EAST will be active and EU-WEST inactive.
- We want to have two SQS queue in each account (eu-west, us-east).
- When EU-WEST is active, we want only SQS queue in EU-WEST working and processing events.
- When we switch to DR we want to make EU-WEST SQS inactive and make SQS in US-EAST active.

There is a Lambda trigger on each SQS.

The problem we might face here is: Both SQS queues will process events since it subscribes to the same SNS topic. And since it is connected to a Lambda function, both will process events.

I don't want this to happen. I want only one pair of SQS and Lambda functions working at a time - either EU-WEST or US-EAST. I know this can be achieved by removing the Lambda trigger on the inactive region.

Just looking for a better approach.

Comment: **Side-note:** Amazon SQS and AWS Lambda are **regional services** that run across multiple availability zones. For High Availability, it is normally recommended to run across multiple AZs or use regional services. Thus, your solution is already highly available, but you are of course welcome to pursue a multi-region approach too.

Comment: *"Both SQS queues will process events since it connects to the same source."*  SQS queues don't connect to "sources," producers connect to queues... so what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Both SQS subscribes to the same SNS .

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution here.

We need to check the Route53 to find the current active region for the application.
In DR region, when we receive a message on SQS , it will trigger the lambda. The lambda checks for active region based on route53 or ALB dns . If it finds the region is not active/live , it will skip processing of the message and hence the SQS queue will clear up on DR.

So live region Lambda will  be actively processing SQS messages whereas the DR one will skip all the processing.

This idea should work for the scenario I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @Niketh Would you be able to share your architecture diagram with me. I have a similar use case where SQS is my ingress point, and i want a failover strategy across 2 regions